# Swift using static library compiled sources as Objective-C++

Tags: c++, ios

I am new to Swift. Recently I encounter a problem
There is a static library compiled sources as Objective-C++. For example, "import " in a .h file like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <map>

@interface CppLib : NSObject

@end
```

Now I create a new swift project, include the .a and .h file created by the static library project. Add a new bridging file named "Swift_CppLib-Bridging-Header.h":

```
#ifndef Swift_CppLib_Bridging_Header_h
#define Swift_CppLib_Bridging_Header_h

#import "CppLib.h"

#endif
```

Then CMD+B, build the project failed:

```
/Users/air/Somnus/CodeDemo/Swift_CppLib/Swift_CppLib/Swift_CppLib-Bridging-Header.h:12:9: note: in file included from /Users/air/Somnus/CodeDemo/Swift_CppLib/Swift_CppLib/Swift_CppLib-Bridging-Header.h:12:
#import "CppLib.h"
        ^
/Users/air/Somnus/CodeDemo/Swift_CppLib/Swift_CppLib/Lib/CppLib.h:10:9: error: 'map' file not found
#import <map>
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/air/Somnus/CodeDemo/Swift_CppLib/Swift_CppLib/Swift_CppLib-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Who could help me fix this problem? Thank for any hint!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to make sure that no c++ or objective-c++ is visible in the header that you're exporting to swift. Apple in their wisdom decided not to support c++ in swift. In my view this was a terrible decision on their part... but I don't work there so have no say in it :)

So you'll need to wrap the library in a thin obj-c wrapper unfortunately... or (IMHO) do the wise thing and avoid swift like the plague. It's just a convoluted syntactic sugar coating over objective-c and unfortunately you can't write a serious application in swift without fully understanding objective-c.

`</rant>` :)

Comment: You're saying it like it's merely for lack of interest rather than because C++ might just be the most complex language around.

Comment: @zneak complexity in computer science never goes away. Some languages try to hide it but sooner or later you need to understand what goes on under the covers. The answer is correct btw. :)

Comment: Saying you can't write a serious app in Swift without understanding Obj-C is false.

Comment: Your answer is an opinion and I firmly stand by the downvote I gave it.

Comment: The Swift team, which is readily accessible through the Swift mailing lists, repeatedly said that they would love to support C++. Major problems are that Swift has no move semantics; only shallow copy semantics; no non-type template arguments; no references.

Comment: you can add to that list, "poor exception support, no real RAII, a convoluted syntax". A rushed attempt to programming iOS easier that actually makes it more fiddly. Poor effort D-. See me after class :)

Comment: You mean "no exception support", and all of these are why it has no C++ compatibility, not because Apple thought it was "wise" to avoid it. I am absolutely astounded that you try to say that Swift has a convoluted syntax in a discussion about C++.

Comment: A discussion around syntax preferences is probably going to lead nowhere. Swift's ! and ? modifiers are an attempt to bring some provability around program logic because the underlying obj-c reference can exist while improperly constructed. It does not address the root cause - which is that RAII is not possible with obj-c and therefore with swift, because it is fundamentally a wrapper for obj-c. In terms of proving program correctness this makes it no better than a scripting language. Preferences aside, c++ is not about nice syntax or simplicity, it's about provability (at least for me).